# Why from $x<t\Rightarrow y\leq t$ does it follow $y\leq x$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

This trick is used by Rudin in his "Functional Analysis" to prove a certain inequality:
[image]

In essence, he shows that, given some numbers $x,y,t$, if $x<t$, then necessarily $y\leq t$ (why this is true I understand) and that, because this works for every $t$ (that fulfills the inequality $x<t$), from this it automatically follows that $y\leq x$. The final implication I don't understand, why exactly does this
$$((x<t)\Rightarrow(y\leq t))\implies(y\leq x)$$
work?

I feel like an idiot for not understanding this, it seems like it should be trivial.

Comment: More precisely: $(\forall t(x<t\Rightarrow y\leq t))\implies(y\leq x)$.

Comment: @TonyK, see, I wanted to add the quantor, but I wasn't sure how it'd read mathematically - "for all $t$ such that $x<t$ holds, $y\leq t$ holds as well" or "for every real number holds $x<t$ and consequently $y\leq t$".

Comment: The parentheses make that clear $-$ your second interpretation would be $((\forall t(x<t))\implies y\le t)\implies y\le x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By way of contradiction, let
$$x< t \implies y\leq t$$
but $y>x$. Then let $t = \frac{x+y}2$ and observe how $x=\frac{x+x}2 <\frac{x+y}2 = t$ but $y=\frac{y+y}2 > \frac{x+y}2 = t$ so the implication fails. Thus you must have $y\leq x$.

Edit:
This may feel dodgy, so if you want to think more like someone wanting to understand analysis, you could think about how this holds for all $t$ such $x< t \leq y$. Thus you cannot have any $t$ such $x<t\leq y$, so you cannot have $y$ to be greater than $x$.
A convenient choice is usually their average, of course. And thinking BWOC is often a decent way to cheese analysis.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, both rigorously with averages and intuitively (if $x<y$ were true, the interval $(x,y)$ would be non-empty and that would contradict the condition $x<t\implies y\leq t$). Thanks!